# Class from Interface.cll

Tags: class, interface, c++-cli

I'm trying to implement a class instance of an interface class. Exploring the interface (.NET DLL) with the project explorer, it says:

```
bool CreateInstance(SharedLibrary::MemoryArbiter^ pntMemory,
                    SharedLibrary::clsMessageQueue^ pntMessageQueue, 
                    SharedLibrary::clsGPIO^ pntGPIO, 
                    SharedLibrary::Types^ pntProgramSettings, 
                    SharedLibrary::DisplayDriver^ pntDisplayDriver)

Member from Plugin_Interface::IPlugin
```

But if I write in my MyClass.h:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace SharedLibrary;

namespace MyCppPlugin {
    [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets::Class | AttributeTargets::Method | 
                             AttributeTargets::Property | AttributeTargets::Field, 
                             AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
    ref class MyPlugin abstract : public Plugin_Interface::IPlugin
    {
    bool CreateInstance(SharedLibrary::MemoryArbiter^ pntMemory, 
                 SharedLibrary::clsMessageQueue^ pntMessageQueue, 
                 SharedLibrary::clsGPIO^ pntGPIO, SharedLibrary::Types^ 
                 pntProgramSettings, SharedLibrary::DisplayDriver^ pntDisplayDriver);
    };
};
```

It says: "error C3766: Missing implementation of Plugin_Interface::IPlugin::CreateInstace(...)

What the heck do I do wrong?

**EDIT:**

Forgot the abstract statement.

And: Why is it saying "IntelliSense: Class can not implement interface member function "Plugin_Interface::IPlugin::CreateInstance" (declared in "Plugin_Interface.dll")"

???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Thanks to Hans Passant who gave me so many hints :)

To export the function it has to implement the Interface 1:1. The export statement has to be added over the class header:

```
[Export(IPlugin::typeid)]
public ref class MyPlugin : public Plugin_Interface::IPlugin
```

And: While VB.NET will compile to "Any CPU" and C++/CLI will compile to Win64/Win32 it will missfit. Both Projects have to have the same target - either 64bit OR 32bit.

Now it works.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: And what in your opinion was the answer then?

Answer (score 1):

You got a lot more diagnostic messages from this snippet, you are making several mistakes:

- [AttributeUsage] is only valid on a class that derives from System::Attribute.  You no doubt need to use some kind of attribute so that the plugin host can recognize your class as a valid plugin candidate, I can't guess what that attribute might be.
- A method that implements an interface method should be *public*.
- A method that implements an interface method must be *virtual*.
- The method signature must be an **exact** match with the interface method declaration.
- Just in case: you must actually implement the method, not just declare it.

The third and forth bullets are the chief reasons for the "must provide an implementation of the interface method" compile error.  So proper code ought to resemble something like this:

```
[NoIdeaWhatAttribute]
public ref class MyPlugin : public Plugin_Interface::IPlugin {
public:
    virtual bool CreateInstance(SharedLibrary::MemoryArbiter^% pntMemory,
                                SharedLibrary::clsMessageQueue^% pntMessageQueue,
                                SharedLibrary::clsGPIO^% pntGPIO, 
                                SharedLibrary::Types^% pntProgramSettings,
                                SharedLibrary::DisplayDriver^% pntDisplayDriver)
    {
        // Todo...
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your hints.

Now I have it like:

  virtual bool CreateInstance(SharedLibrary::MemoryArbiter^, SharedLibrary::clsMessageQueue^, SharedLibrary::clsGPIO^, SharedLibrary::Types^, SharedLibrary::DisplayDriver^) = Plugin_Interface::IPlugin::CreateInstance;
  virtual bool DeleteInstance(void) sealed = Plugin_Interface::IPlugin::DeleteInstance;

Compile error about missing implementation of DeleteInstance (and so on) are gone now, but it still claims CreateInstance (the part after the = ).

Comment: That's not what I recommended you'd write.  Using explicit interface method implementations is fine but don't actually make any sense whatsoever for a plugin.  I don't see a mistake in the comment but it is hard to read and I can't see the error message.  Properly quoting error messages is rather important when you ask for help, you didn't do that in your original question either.

Comment: Actually it is for a plugin which should use MEF for communicating with the host application. Therefore I need to implement the IPlugin Interface completely. However, I'm using a german version of VS and so the error messages won't help that much.

Comment: Changing it in your suggested way it says: Fehler 1 error C3766: "MyCppPlugin::MyPlugin" muss eine Implementierung für die bool Plugin_Interface::IPlugin::CreateInstance(SharedLibrary::MemoryArbiter ^%,SharedLibrary::clsMessageQueue ^%,SharedLibrary::clsGPIO ^%,SharedLibrary::Types ^%,SharedLibrary::DisplayDriver ^%)-Schnittstellenmethode bereitstellen. s:\dropbox\dropbox\nmt\windows software\grafiksimulator\cli_demo_plugin\MyPlugin.h 19 1 CLI_DEMO_PLUGIN

Comment: Hallelujah, a real error message.  The difference between `^%` and `^` is not a subtle one that you can just ignore.  Not in English either :)

Comment: Oh you holy bimbam :) Haven't seen it :)

However: Do you have any idea what the export statement should look like to use the MEF? There's no namespace System.ComponentModell.Composition.Export as it is told in some examples.

Comment: It is absolutely strange that there's absolutely no information on how to export the plugin definition. I'm trying to find something since several days but was not successful so far -.-

Comment: It just takes adding an assembly reference for the System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll assembly.  Click the Ask Question button if googling "c++/cli add assembly reference" doesn't help.

Comment: Hi Hans Passant. I included the reference as you told but this won't make any changes. I somehow need an export statement. I tried hundreds of different options but none of them worked or even compiled... :(